# SQL Delete Subquery when tables have 1:N Relationship

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, constraints

So, I am trying to complete a query to delete rows based on an attribute value. Something like this.

```
DELETE FROM SPORTING_CLUBS
WHERE state = 'NY';
```

However, the primary key of the SPORTING_CLUBS table (CLUB_ID) is the foreign key/parent of two child tables CLUB_ACTIVITY and CLUB_MEMBERSHIP. I am having trouble with the logic I need to follow to successfully delete the rows in the two child tables before the delete operation is completed in the SPORTING_CLUBS table.

Comment: You are following the logic correctly.  You need to delete the records that refer to this table.  You can do it automatically by defining the references as "on delete cascade".

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I'm just not sure the way to go about this without using the statement you suggested. I understand why the code above is thrown a constraint error, I just don't know how to fix it with a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

if you can't change the FOREIGN KEY constraints to have the `ON CASCADE DELETE` clause added you will need to delete the records from the child tables before deleting from the master table. I recommend you using the transaction to preserve data integrity

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM CLUB_ACTIVITY 
WHERE CLUB_ID IN (
                  SELECT CLUB_ID FROM SPORTING_CLUBS
                  WHERE state = 'NY');
DELETE FROM CLUB_MEMBERSHIP
WHERE CLUB_ID IN (
                  SELECT CLUB_ID FROM SPORTING_CLUBS
                  WHERE state = 'NY');
DELETE FROM SPORTING_CLUBS
WHERE state = 'NY';
COMMIT;
```